# Does Spark JDBC use a connection pool to maintain connections, and if not, could it?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I use [Spark JDBC](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) to load a dataset from a MySQL DB. CPU profiling revealed that a significant amount of time is being spent on opening connections. The Spark JDBC stack appears to open a new connection on each table partition it attempts to read. Is my understanding correct?

It looks like I have the ability to define a [ConnectionProvider](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/connection/ConnectionProvider.scala#L107C30-L107C30) and specify it using the `connectionProvider` option. The default connection provider is the [BasicConnectionProvider](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/connection/BasicConnectionProvider.scala#L42) but I could maybe create a sort of PooledConnectionProvider that makes use of something like HikariCP.

If I know that my application will be running in executors with 5 cores, then I am thinking a connection pool of size 5 should ensure that when a new task replaces an old one it should be able to make use of a connection already established by an earlier task.

However I am not sure how safe that approach is. I would think that if pooling connections in Spark JDBC were useful or safe then it would already be officially supported but it doesn't appear to be.

Should I abandon this approach?

Comment: "if pooling connections in Spark JDBC were useful or safe then it would already be officially supported but it doesn't appear to be". Overall spark jdbc as many room of improvement, so no worries. BTW what about using an external connection pooler (kind of pgbouncer if existfor mysql)

Comment: @parisni that is comforting (though also a little concerning?). if by external do you mean a service running somewhere in the cluster that acts as a proxy between spark JDBC and the DB? that is something I considered but was not aware of how difficult it would be. I was not aware of pgbouncer